# Undefined refernce with GStream and GLib

Tags: c++, cmake, gstreamer, glib

I'am trying to compile my Ultralight project for linux using cmake. But there is this on error that I cant get fixed:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/e/Programming/C_C++/ultralight-sdk-latest-linux-x64/bin/libgstreamer-full-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_time_zone_new_identifier'

/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/e/Programming/C_C++/ultralight-sdk-latest-linux-x64/bin/libgstreamer-full-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_memdup2'
```

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.0)
project(BlackBoard)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Windows")
    set(ULTRALIGHT_SDK_DIR E:/Programming/C_C++/ultralight-sdk-latest-win-x64)
elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Linux")
    set(ULTRALIGHT_SDK_DIR /mnt/e/Programming/C_C++/ultralight-sdk-latest-linux-x64)
endif()



IF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Windows")
    add_executable(BlackBoard main.cpp)

    include_directories(${ULTRALIGHT_SDK_DIR}/include)
    link_directories(${ULTRALIGHT_SDK_DIR}/lib)

    target_link_libraries(BlackBoard ${ULTRALIGHT_SDK_DIR}/lib/Ultralight.lib)
    target_link_libraries(BlackBoard ${ULTRALIGHT_SDK_DIR}/lib/UltralightCore.lib)
    target_link_libraries(BlackBoard ${ULTRALIGHT_SDK_DIR}/lib/AppCore.lib)
    target_link_libraries(BlackBoard ${ULTRALIGHT_SDK_DIR}/lib/WebCore.lib)
elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Linux")
    FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
    PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GLIB REQUIRED glib-2.0)

    include_directories(${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${GLIB_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    link_libraries(${GLIB_LIBRARIES})

    link_libraries(X11)

    include_directories(${ULTRALIGHT_SDK_DIR}/include)
    link_directories(${ULTRALIGHT_SDK_DIR}/bin)
    link_libraries(
            UltralightCore
            AppCore
            Ultralight
            WebCore
    )

    add_executable(BlackBoard main.cpp)

else()
    message(STATUS ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME})
endif()


add_custom_command(TARGET BlackBoard POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${ULTRALIGHT_SDK_DIR}/bin" $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:BlackBoard>)
add_custom_command(TARGET BlackBoard POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/" "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:BlackBoard>/assets")
add_custom_command(TARGET BlackBoard POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${ULTRALIGHT_SDK_DIR}/resources" "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:BlackBoard>/assets/resources")
enter code here
```

I don't know what to provide and so as I really am clueless so feel free to ask for anything, at the end I am the one that wants help.

Comment: So you have **already created** shared library `libgstreamer-full-1.0.so` which contains undefined reference errors. These errors cannot be caused by your project: the library itself is **broken**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that means I will have to rebuild it, right?

Comment: Unresolved symbol `g_memdup2` could also mean, that gstreamer is built against newer glib, than you have in your system. Of that you have two glibc installed in your system. Rebuilding gstreamer against your glibc (and other libraries) sounds like a good idea.